# How to create map tiles out of 25 images?

Tags: android, offline

I am an absolute beginner of GIS and have the following situation:

- I need to create an offline map for Android,
- I have 25 pictures that represent a region that needs to be mapped in my application,
- I have the top left and the bottom right coordinates of the map (of the 5x5 grid comprised of the 25 images).
- I am thinking of using the Nutiteq SDK manage the map in my application (in order to add markers and user position).

The Nutiteq Maps SDK supports: MBTiles, MGMaps, GeoTIFF and other formats.

How do I create a usable format file out of 25 images and top left, bottom right coordinates?

Comment: Your images are georeferenced? If yes, use fme for the creation of webtile.

Comment: @twisig thanks twisig bu they are not georeferenced :-( BTW what is fme? Thanks LISA

Comment: Fme is an etl software (extract  transformation and load)

Comment: Tile creation with gdal2tiles is explained here: http://build-failed.blogspot.de/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html . Maybe you can derive something from that.